# Unable to execute the code 'matplotlib.pyplot as plt' in pycharm AttributeError: 'InputHookManager' object has no attribute '_stdin_file'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Hi I am using Ubuntu: and Pycharm latest version(2019.2):
if i import only matplotlib it does not show any error,
however if i try to execute matplotlib.pyplot as plt it shows me 
below error: Please refer the note section below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Backend GTK3Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode 
on.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sarfi/.local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-2-a0d2faabd9e9>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/snap/pycharm- 
community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", 
line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sarfi/.local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2362, in <module>
install_repl_displayhook()
File "/home/sarfi/.local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 126, in 
install_repl_displayhook
ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 146, in enable_gui
return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 536, in enable_gui
return gui_hook(app)
File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 413, in enable_gtk3
self.set_inputhook(create_inputhook_gtk3(self._stdin_file))
AttributeError: 'InputHookManager' object has no attribute '_stdin_file'
```

NOTE: I tried uninstalling `matplotlib` and `pip3` and reinstalled it,
I also installed the `Six` : `pip3 install Six`, however, the issue remains 
the same

Comment: This is an internal pycharm error. You can contact pycharm support about it.

Comment: Thank you! I have queried them lets see what they have to say on this.

Comment: This is the reply from pycharm

Comment: Hi Sarfisayyad, thank you for contacting PyCharm support.

The problem is known https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16043, unfortunately, it was not yet addressed. I will ping the responsible developer about the ETA. Meanwhile, please vote for the ticket.

Pavel,
PyCharm QA Engineer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:
Use a different backend (from gtk/gtk3)

```
import matplotlib                #only import mpl first
matplotlib.use("agg")            #then set backend
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,1])
plt.savefig("name.jpg")
```

I haven't tested other backends yet, but this works. Of course this is no permanent solution but just a quick emergency fix if you need the figures.

The problem is with gtk/gtk3 (I think).
Also shown in *PY-16043 Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'gtk'*
(see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16043 , which is the link BugsBunny already put).

The Error occurs when the `enable_gtk/enable_gtk3` method is defined. So if you don't use this backend, you avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And it does the trick